# flexslider css causes images to disappear

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, flexslider

I've been toying around with flexslider to add to my website and initially had trouble implementing the features. After inspecting the demo code, i've decided to copy the example code they provide into my own html to see the results. Following the website's tutorial

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

I then copied the demo file's images

```
        <div class="flexslider">
      <ul class="slides">
        <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_cheesecake_brownie.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_lemon.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_donut.jpg" />
            </li>
            <li>
            <img src="images/kitchen_adventurer_caramel.jpg" />
            </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

to replicate the slider they have, however these images do not show up at all. Once the CSS file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
```

is removed, it shows up once again. Does anyone know why the images seem to disappear, or how I can get it to properly format into the flexslider demo.

Answer (score 0):

Flexslider hides the slides until it's been initialized to prevent [FOUS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content).

You can see the following css here: https://github.com/woothemes/FlexSlider/blob/master/css/base.less

```
.slides {
    > li {
       display: none; 
       -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    }
}
```

Comment: I see, thanks for clarifying. So to reiterate, I need to initialize the jquery portion until it will show? I'm still having some trouble emulating the demo, despite following the tutorial step by step.

Comment: Are you initializing it somewhere? I've made an example that is essentially the same as yours but uses different images: https://jsfiddle.net/4wL5tp2h/

Comment: Yes, they're all in the same folder. I'm still fairly new to javascript, and i'm struggling to initialize the javascript portion it seems. I'm essentially copying the third portion here


` <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('.flexslider').flexslider();
  });
</script>

Answer (score 0):

After much testing, I noticed that running the javascript files inside of the head does not initialize my files properly. It seems for me I can only initialize the javascript at the body of the page before the closing body tag.